# Full index scan search contains algorithm

Tags: mysql, database, algorithm, search

Let's suppose a search is performed and it misses the index and does a full table scan. For the purposes of this question:

```
SELECT * FROM bigtable WHERE name like '%someone%'
```

This will need to do a full table scan on the `name` field. Is it known what string-search algorithm is used for these full table scans on open-source databases such as postgres, mysql, h2, or sqlite? I'm guessing every last piece of these databases are optimized (even when the operation is going to be slow), so was wondering what different techniques are used when doing these full table scans / without any kind of index.

Comment: The I/O cost will typically dominate by a large factor, so the particular string-search algorithm is not important unless it's exceptionally slow, and it won't be exceptionally slow.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL it doesn't look like it's very optimised. It's a relatively straightforward iteration with `memcmp` for the multibyte characters. See [source](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/4869291f7ee258e136ef03f5a50135fe7329ffb9/strings/ctype-mb.cc#L237)

Not sure about other engines.